# Remove miss-matched data in columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How would I remove data rows in a dataset which do not match the dictionary values of two columns. for example take the snippet of my data set.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuHqy.png]

I want to remove the rows where the data doesn't match the dictionary like in row 6 and apply this function to a large data set.

dictionary = SiteID, Location [188:A, 203:B, 206:C, 270:D, 463:E]

Comment: Please post a working example of your data and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Where is your dict ?

Comment: I posted I link to my data and haven't got any code examples as i'm very new to coding and don't know where to start

Answer (score 1):

Try to do with `merge`

```
d = {188:'A', 203:'B', 206:'C', 270:'D', 463:'E'}
out = df.merge(pd.Series(d).rename_axis('SiteID').to_frame('Location').reset_index(),how='left')
```

Comment: Hi @Beny. Wouldn't this only test whether the SiteID column match the keys in the dictionary? Meaning that if there's a match based on SiteID's, it won't consider the mismatch on the Locations (if exists) ?

Comment: @sophocles right , let me update

Comment: @BENY Can you have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70426909/)?